# increasing fs.file-max: what are the others kernel params need adjustments (for running kafka)

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, file-descriptors, sysctl

For running a kafka service (with jbod disks, where we encountered problems due to too many open files) with an increased `LimitNOFILE` of 500000,
we decided to increase the `fs.file-max` from `500000` to `1000000` on our RHEL 7.x server.

As I understand when increasing `fs.file` it also has an impact about open more file descriptors.

so we want to understand if other kernel parameters should be update also when increasing the `fs.file-max` ?

from reading , I saw that `inode-max` , should be  “3-4 times larger than the value in file-max,

but we not found this parameter on our server

```
 more /proc/sys/fs/inode-max
/proc/sys/fs/inode-max: No such file or directory


more /etc/sysctl.conf
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).
fs.file-max = 500000
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50
net.core.somaxconn=1024
```

Comment: hi, so, `fs.file-max` is the maximum number of open files. What other things would you need to increase to *solve the problem you're having*? We don't know what that problem is, so it's kind of hard to know what else you need to increase!

Comment: lets say I want to increase the fs.file-max to 20000000 , so that it? , or maybe since we increased the fs.file-max we should increase or update additional params?

Comment: again, what other parameters do you *need*? I can't tell you what you need - I don't even know why you're increasing `file-max`. **Tell us your problem before discussing the solution**, engineering rule nr. 1!

Comment: we increase the fs.max-file to 1000000 because we increased the LimitNOFILE to 500000 for kafka service , ( since we have kafka service that using jbod disks , then we faced the problem about too many open files ) , so we increase the imitNOFILE=500000 ,

Comment: I added that info into your question, it seems very important! Can you check whether my edit makes sense to you?

Comment: yes the update was good

Answer (score 0):

the `inode-max` file doesn't exist because this sysfs was removed starting with linux-2.4; where there was no longer a static limit on the number of inodes.

> /proc/sys/fs/inode-max (only present until Linux 2.2)
> This file contains the maximum number of in-memory inodes.
> This value should be 3–4 times larger than the value in
> file-max, since stdin, stdout and network sockets also
> need an inode to handle them.  When you regularly run out
> of inodes, you need to increase this value.
>
> ```
>   Starting with Linux 2.4, there is no longer a static limit
>   on the number of inodes, and this file is removed.
> ```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

To my knowledge, you should not need to adjust any other kernel parameters when adjusting `fs.file-max`.

That said, on systemd systems; sometimes you may need to set resource limits in `/etc/systemd/user.conf` (for user) or `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (system-wide), as systemd may override or ignore resource limits, in some circumstances.